# Macro launches userform from activesheet, but want to auto-paste cell value from activesheet into userform's combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, copy-paste

Looking for a little help here. Summary below.

**GOAL:** When I run a macro module from an activesheet, the following steps are automated:

1. Launches a userform with multiple ComboBoxes and buttons
2. Copies the text in cells(activecell.row, 1)
3. Pastes the text into the 1st ComboBox on userform labeled DPComboBox

I can do 1 and 2, but 3 fails whether I do the pasting in the vba code of the module or the vba code of the ComboBox. I can manually paste once the userform is displayed since the copy works, but I want to automate the step.

**Macro Module**

```
Sub Show_Quick_Commands()
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Copy
    CommandsUserForm.Show vbModeless
    DPComboBox.Select
    DPComboBox.Paste
End Sub
```

**Macro ComboBox** (currently not attempting paste here, but happy with everything else in this code)

```
Private Sub DPComboBox_Change()
    ActiveDPLastRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To ActiveDPLastRow
        If (ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = DPComboBox.Value) Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Copy
            PCComboBox.Paste
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Copy
            DISComboBox.Paste
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you want to try this : In your Show_Quick_Commands Sub, remove the last two lines then after `CommandsUserForm.Show vbModeless` add this line  `CommandsUserForm.DPComboBox.additem activecell.value:  DPComboBox.value=activecell.value`. Please note there is no checking whether the added item name already exist in DPComboBox.

Comment: or if your DPComboBox already populated where the item name is the same string with any cell you will activate it, then just remove the `CommandsUserForm.DPComboBox.additem activecell.value` line.